# SAS find/replace process between tables

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a table called EMAILLIST where elements are lists of names. Also, suppose I have a table called EMAILNAME which connects someone's first/last to their email address. I want to write a process that will basically do this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML Tables</title>
</head>

<body>
  EMAILLIST
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Lists</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Gooberson;Becky Gooberson;Rachel Gooberson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donald Goob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barack Goobama</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>EMAILNAME
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Gooberson</td>
      <td>MG@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Becky Gooberson</td>
      <td>BG@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rachel Gooberson</td>
      <td>RG@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donald Goob</td>
      <td>DG@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barack Goobama</td>
      <td>BRG@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<BR>
<BR>RESULTTABLE
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Lists</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MG@gmail.com;BG@gmail.com;RG@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DG@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BRG@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your question about parsing the above HTML into a dataset (and producing the final table), or producing all of the above HTML from a dataset? Can you provide a sample of your dataset in that case?

Answer (score 2):

I'd first recommend a slight modification to the structure of the `EMAILLIST` dataset, in a way that would allow merging your two tables into one. This implies the creation a new column (which I called `group`) which will be used in the final step.

So now, in the `EMAILLIST` dataset...

- The `name` field contains only **one name per line**, allowing us to merge your two tables into one.
- The `group` variable keeps track of the names/emails which belong together in the final table.

Note: *I kept the "Lists" entry in the final table, not sure why you need it, but in any case, removing it would not be difficult.*

### Sample data

```
data EMAILLIST;
  informat group 8. name $56.;
  infile datalines dlm="|";
  input group name; 
  datalines;
.|Lists
1|Michael Gooberson
1|Becky Gooberson
1|Rachel Gooberson
2|Donald Goob
3|Barack Goobama
;


data EMAILNAME;
  informat name email $56.;
  infile datalines dlm=",";
  input name email;
  datalines;
Michael Gooberson,MG@gmail.com
Becky Gooberson,BG@gmail.com
Rachel Gooberson,RG@gmail.com
Donald Goob,DG@gmail.com
Barack Goobama,BRG@gmail.com
;
```

### Merge the two tables by `name`

```
proc sql;
  create table NAMES_EMAILS as
    select L.group,
           L.name,
           E.email
      from emaillist as L
      left join emailname as E
             on L.name = E.name
      order by L.group;
quit;
```

### Create final table

```
data RESULTS;
  set NAMES_EMAILS;
  by group;

  format emails $256.;
  retain emails "";

  if group = . then do;
    emails = name;
  end;

  else if first.group then do;
    emails = email;
  end;

  else if not first.group then do;
    emails = catx(";",emails, email);
  end;

  if last.group then output;

  keep emails;
run;
```

### Results

[image: Results table]

If you need to generate an html file showing the contents of the results table, just use `ODS`, like so:

```
ods html body="path/to/resulttable.html";
proc print data=results noobs;
run;
ods html close;
```